# Mac audio intermittently stops working

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, audio

My mac audio randomly stops working every few minutes.

This is what the top bar looks like when it is and is not working:

[image]

As you can see from the image above, when the audio is working, I see all my output devices and all of the output sources work. However, every few minutes the audio stops working and I see no sources in the menu bar. When this happens, the microphones also stop working.

I have already tried the following with no success:

1. Reset the NVRAM/PRAM
2. Reset the SMC
3. Ran Apple Diagnostics with no issues found
4. Boot into safe mode
5. Upgrading to latest OS version

The only thing that I have not tried is resetting the entire computer. I would like to avoid this as much as possible.

Information about my Mac model:
MacBook Pro (late 2013)
8 gb RAM
256 gb SSD

Comment: First thing I'd do is uninstall Sound Booster, reboot & test again. Direct download link - https://froyosoft.com/uninstallsoundbooster.php

Comment: @Tetsujin Uninstalled the sound booster and it has been working properly for the past 24 hours. According to the reviews of this sound booster, a lot of people appear to have this same issue with it.

Comment: I don't know of any freeware replacement - [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) is good & far more comprehensive, but 30 bucks or so [depends on country & tax]